# 3D scanner file import

Tags: modeling

I have a few 3D scanner meshs and I have a few .stl and .ply but when I import them in to blender I lost the color... why? and how do I fix it ? also I got a file called model_texture.jpg that comes with it, with is weird have has color on it, so I think that is important somehow, but I do not know what to do with it.

Comment: someone down vote my question and I want to know why? I am new to Blender that is why I am on here asking and if this is so easy how about tell me how to do it.

Comment: Hello and welcome :). The .jpg file contains a surface texture for your model. You probably need to apply it to your model (@RobertGützkow kindly provided a useful thread) if you want your colors to appear.